# Django REST API to receive images

Tags: django, image, api, rest

I have a Django project using Tastypie as its main API and it works ok. But now I want to be able to receive images through the API (coming from phones and such). It looks like Tastypie is not quite ready yet in that field. I'm ready to try something else just for that matter, or even write a custom view. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard Django view can technically serve as an API endpoint, too, so why not just write a view that handles a POST payload?

You could even make a form which you use to validate the input, even if your client device isn't using that form to capture content - as long as the fields and their criteria match up, it'll still fit.